# How to step through multiple UITextFields

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I have four UITextFields that I would like to use in a UIAlertView, Currently this is what it is looking like

[image]

What I would like to be able to do is restrict each box to 4 characters once each field once that 4 character limit is reached then I would like the next UITextField to become the first responder.

I would also like to be able to do this in reverse so if characters are being deleted once there are no characters available in the second field go to the first and start deleting etc.

Currently my code is pretty sloppy as I am just trying to get something like this working.. so this is what it looks like so far.

//prompt user to enter registration here
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Register Device" message:@" " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 53, 30)];

UITextField *myTextField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(77, 45, 53, 30)];
UITextField *myTextField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(142, 45, 53, 30)];
UITextField *myTextField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(207, 45, 53, 30)];

// need to do something with first reasponder once 4 digits has been entered per box etc.
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];

myTextField.placeholder =@"AAAA";
myTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
myTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
myTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

myTextField1.placeholder =@"AAAA";
myTextField1.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
myTextField1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
myTextField1.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

myTextField2.placeholder =@"AAAA";
myTextField2.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
myTextField2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
myTextField2.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

myTextField3.placeholder =@"AAAA";
myTextField3.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
myTextField3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
myTextField3.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myTextField1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myTextField2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myTextField3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[alert addSubview:myTextField];
[alert addSubview:myTextField1];
[alert addSubview:myTextField2];
[alert addSubview:myTextField3];

[alert show];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

// UPDATE:
 this is how I am trying to use the delegate method

```
//.h
<UITextFieldDelegate>

//.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//..
    [self.myTextField setDelegate:self];
    [self.myTextField1 setDelegate:self];
    [self.myTextField2 setDelegate:self];
    [self.myTextField3 setDelegate:self];
//..
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
     NSLog(@"yay");
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

I tried the code below, and does work, but for a reason if you change the FirstResponder, the text won't get written. So I modified the function. You should do this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.text.length >= MAX_LENGTH)
        return NO;

    if((textField.text.length + string.length) >= MAX_LENGTH)
    {
        int currentTag = textField.tag;

        if(currentTag == 4)
            return YES;

        UITextField *newTextField = (UITextField *) [textField.superview viewWithTag:(currentTag+1)];
        [newTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    }
    return YES; //you probably want to review this...
}
```

Any way, this doesn't work when you wan't to delete content, but that's easy solved if you change the code to check the range of the changes.

I made a sample project, you can get it here: [TextFieldTest](http://raspu.net/TextFieldTest.zip)

---

This is how I would do it, using the textfield delegate, you can check the new inserted characters, if you reach the maximum, you move to the next textfield:

```
static int MAX_LENGTH = 4;
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if((textField.text.length + string.length) >= MAX_LENGTH)
   {
       //Get next TextField... A simple way to do this:
       UITextField *newTextField = [textField.superview viewWithTag:(textField.tag+1)];
       [newTextField becomeFirstResponder];
       //remember to set the tags in order
   }
   return YES; //you probably want to review this... 
}
```

(Sorry if dosen't compile I just wrote it here directly)

Good Luck!

Comment: Okay I will try to work with this.. just having an issue with my shouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate method not being called even though I have added UITextFieldDelegate into the header and also setting the delegate in the viewDidLoad method..

Comment: I have updated my question with example code at the bottom showing how I am trying to use the textfield delegate.

Comment: you are doing everything at the AppDelegate? That's not recommended, but besides that, I can't see what may be wrong, sorry.

Comment: okay I have removed it from the AppDelegate as I thought that might be the problem after reading a comment somewhere else.. I have set it up in its own viewController I call from the appDelegate... still no luck the delegate methods are not being accessed.. what the heck is going on lol

Comment: I am going to try taking the text boxes out of the alertview and see if the delegate works then

Comment: That was I was thinking, The text fields are inside the AlertView, that is shown inside, if I don't remember incorrectly, another UIWindow. So maybe that's the reason why you can't access the delegate or something...

Comment: Okay I will report back here with my findings.. such a pain though LOL

Comment: okay, so figured out why the delegate methods were not being used. When I did this all in another viewController and loaded it as a subview to the mainView it wouldnt accessed.. If i just add everything to the mainView the delegate methods work... so weird.. Im not sure what would cause this but this worked for me. thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set delegate for these text fields and implement your business logic (set one of the text fields as the new first responder) in the delegate methods.